# Laravel-Mix Font-awesome can't installed properly with npm

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, npm, font-awesome, laravel-mix

I have installed font-awesome with `npm` with following command :

```
npm install font-awesome --save
```

And then i have add following line in `app.scss`

```
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

Then i have run  `npm run watch`

I have checked manually font-awesome folder is there inside the `node_modules` directory.
But in my webpage icon not displayed and in console i have seen following Error

> GET
>   http://localhost/fonts/vendor/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?af7ae505a9eed503f8b8e6982036873e
>   net::ERR_ABORTED  GET

How do i resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Since your are using Laravel, you need to write the following line in `resources/asset/sass/_variables.scss`:

```
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts/";
```

Now in your `resources/assets/sass/app.scss`, write:

```
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

Comment: I tried with your solution, but noting updated.same Error showing